# MS Access. Store an ID while showing an user-friendly control with Dlookup

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, controls, lookup

I am doing a simple database in Access for recipes. I took the ingredient list from the USDA, that includes thousands of ingredients, that have a proper ID and the description.

In the new table, RECIPES, I am creating fields Ingredient_1, Ingredient_2, etc.
I want the user to be able to input the ingredients using the description from the USDA table, but being able to store the ingredient ID instead of the description to ensure a good database structure.

I have read the documentation for dlookup extensively, but I am not familiar with SQL or Access. I know how to create the control source for the ingredient input, but it just stores the description.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't put ingrdients into separate columns, rather place them across separate records.  This is a preferable database design in my opinion.

Comment: So, for example, Recipe_ID    Ingredient_ID, where I repeat recipe_ID all times necessary to list all ingredients as records?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I would suggest.  It makes it much easier to query your data.

Comment: Thanks! it is a good idea. How would you store the ingredient_id while showing the user the ingredient description in the control box?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Access.  But someone else can probably help you.

Comment: Use a multi-column combobox for selecting ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have at least 3 tables. Recipes, Ingredients, RecipeIngredients. In Recipes would be fields like RecID, RecipeName, Category, DateLastUsed. Then RecipeIngredients would have fields RecipeID, IngredientID.  Options for data entry form:

1.single form bound to RecipeIngredients with comboboxes to select recipe and ingredients

2.main form bound to Recipes and subform bound to RecipeIngredients with combobox to select ingredients

3.main form bound to Ingredients and subform bound to RecipeIndredients with combobox to select recipe

I suggest option 2 is most appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! I'm following your approach and it is working well with option 2.